# How to check if two childs are present in the xml using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I need to write validation for the below XML. The validation is inside the book tag both the mrp and amount tag should not come only one should be there either mrp or amount. please help me out with writing the logic in XSL.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
    <book> <mrp>121</mrp> <amount>345$</amount></book>
    <book> <mrp>234</mrp></book>
    <book><mrp>567</mrp> <amount>456$</amount> </book>
<books>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xlink"
                version='2.0'>

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="book[child::mrp and child::amount]">
<xsl:value-of select="saxon:line-number()"/>:<xsl:value-of select="saxon:column-number()"/><xsl:text>Either mrp or amount values should be present but not both</xsl:text>
<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="saxon:line-number()"/>:<xsl:value-of select="saxon:column-number()"/>Either mrp or amount values should be present but not both".."/></xsl:message>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not that Schematron allows you to define such constraints outside of XSLT e.g. `<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2"><pattern><rule context="book"><assert test="not(mrp and amount)">book should not have both mrp and amount child.</assert></rule></pattern></schema>`

Comment: `book[child::mrp and child::amount]` looks fine (you could shorten it to `book[mrp and amount]`) so where is your attempt failing, other than tagging it as XSLT 1 but then using version="2.0" and Saxon specific extension?